# Is it OK to update post counts on burnination requests?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-system

Is editing the number of un-deleted tags on [burninate-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) posts to bump them to the top of meta discouraged?

Burninating large tags takes a long time and sometimes the post drops off the first few pages. I feel like bumping it every so often might help keep it visible and encourage more people to join in.

Answer (score 12):

Remember that you can update the progress answer instead!

Every one of the burnination posts, that follow the official burnination procedure, would have an answer to keep progress of the burnination. There you can keep a tag on how many posts are remaining (I usually update the answer, once per day, throughout the duration of the burnination).

However, the other problem raised in this specific question, is with respect to large tags. Tags that are larger than 1000 posts, have an additional step in the burnination procedure where CMs are notified and they delete the tag directly. In these cases you would not need to worry about the tag after it has been cleaned up. The CMs will just nuke the tag directly.

Therefore updating the question with the post count, won't be useful in those case. (Also "won't be useful" ≠ "harmful", so if you're updating the question with the post count, it's not a problem).

So remember the advice:

Less that 1000 tags, call Trogdor:

[image: Trogdor]

More than 1000 tags, call Shogdor:

[image: Shogdor]

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about it—the posts are *always* featured for about a week so they already got *plenty* of attention. They're also usually assisted by SOCVR, plus another chat room of their own, so they're plenty organized.

Sometimes, I used to make frivolous edits on my Meta posts to see if I could get a few more upvotes on them from the bump. If I got anything, it would usually be very little compared to the existing score that they had. I suspect the same of your efforts: everyone who would see it and help out has probably already seen it and is actively helping out. The few that haven't seen it yet but want to pitch in are going to be a drop in the bucket compared to the existing effort.

Oh yeah, plus this sort of thing (editing to bump a question) is generally frowned upon unless your edit is a decent improvement to the post.

Comment: [Trogdor](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor) is where we keep track of the burnation backlog.